# How to make file manager type back navigation with onClick action.

Tags: android

I want to make a **proper back navigation** system just like android File Manager in My Project. I am confused about how to  make this type of View with proper onClick implementation. [image]

Advance thanks.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i am confuse about the concept.

Comment: Generally what they does is save some value for the buttons and on clicking they are moving to backstack.